# Want to compare text in two Mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

I am importing new lines from text files. Table Text_Lines is today's import, Bak_Lines is yesterday. Need to select Text_Lines.text that are not matched in Bak_Lines.text

Tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `text_lines`  (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Text` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `text.text`(`Text`) USING BTREE
)
```

Comment: As a note, this schema could be better using one table with an indexed date column.

Answer (score 0):

Consulting the [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/%2fArticles%2f33052%2fVisual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins), what you need is a *left excluding join*.

[image]

text_lines is A, bak_lines is B. Do a left join on `text`. Then only select those where `bl.text` is null to exclude any columns which match.

```
SELECT tl.text
FROM text_lines tl
LEFT JOIN bak_lines bl
  ON tl.text = bl.text
WHERE bl.text is null
```

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect.